# Google charts does not always load in first attempt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-visualization

I ask advice. Google chart is not always loaded on the first attempt ... how to solve this problem?

[demo](https://floating-peak-23861.herokuapp.com/wwo/weather)

view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Time', 'TempC'],
     <% @data.css("hourly").each do |hrly| %>     
     ['<%= hrly.css("time").text %>',<%= hrly.css("tempC").text %>],
     <% end %>
    ]);
    var options = {
      title: 'Temperature forecast'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></div>
```

controller

```
class WwoController < ApplicationController
def weather
require 'nokogiri'

url = "https://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?q=59.94%2C30.31&num_of_days=4&key=***********************************"
@data = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))

end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use turbolinks, try to disable it in that page, because I have similar problems with google maps apis

to disable turbolinks you can add this to your application.html.erb

```
<body <%= yield(:body_attributes) %>>
```

then in your view.html.erb add this in first line

```
<%= content_for(:body_attributes, 'data-no-turbolink') %>
```

you can also disable turbolink with link_to

```
<%= link_to 'link_name', your_link_path, 'data-no-turbolink' => true %>
```

if you use rails/turbolinks 5
change `data-no-turbolink` into `data-turbolinks` and switch the boolean value

also try to put your javascript in the bottom. to make it loaded after the html dom.

Comment: Thank you. I did it. But this does not work in my case. Maybe I should have used gem googlecharts? Or I need to try highcharts...

Comment: try to put your script in bottom, and your div in top.

Comment: Solved: 
<%= link_to 'link_name', your_link_path, data:{ turbolinks: 'false'} %> 
$ rails version -> Rails 5.1.2